# pygame mixer music ogg playback distorted after long period of idling

Tags: python, audio, pygame

I have a python program that runs on the device (Raspberry Pi Zero W, Raspbian Stretch Lite), and when user pushes certain button, plays an audio file. To do this, I use pygame mixer.music.play() function. One command starts looped playback, another command stops it. And this all works wonderfully without any problem, when the program has been just launched . However, if the system is left running for many hours (or days), something  happens to the sound playback: it does not start immediately, and after certain pause a weird, choppy playback starts: apparently a tiny piece (like 1/8th or 1/10th of a second) of the original sound is rapidly looped, and that tiny piece somewhat changes with time. I have experienced something like this a very long time ago, when DOS game is hindered due to floppy disk reading, and the music playback on Sound Blaster get's stuck into tiny loop of whatever was the last bit of audio data left in the buffer.

I tried to replicate the problem in plain Python console:

```
from pygame import mixer
mixer.init()
mixer.music.load('file.ogg')
mixer.music.play(-1) # Normal playback
mixer.music.stop()
# Much later
mixer.music.play(-1) # Glitchy playback
# Then stop
mixer.music.stop() # Even though the command returns immediately, the audio stops only after some time
```

The code initializes the pygame mixer `mixer.init()` once at the beginning, and reuses the same mixer object all the time. I checked if things would be different if the mixer object would be re-initialized:

```
mixer.quit()
mixer.init()
```

And, indeed, that fixes the problem, and the playback is normal again. Interestingly, it took quite long time for the `mixer.quit()` call to return. Apparently, the mixer destructor had a lot of cleaning to do. I was hoping I could initialize the mixer just once when the program is launched, but now it seems there's a problem with this approach.

Is there any way a single mixer object could be kept live for long time?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and fixed it using a thread that, when the program stops playing music it quits the mixer and init it again

```
def player_handler(self):
    if self.player.mixer.music.get_busy() == False: #music ended
        self.player.mixer.quit()            
        self.player.mixer.init()
```

My handler runs every second and that fixed for me. Not very elegant though...

Comment: I am now avoiding using mixer.music at all. Apparently that's what messes up the memory. If the sounds are short (not sure if compression level matters), then most needs can be satisfied with mixer.Sound objects.